# Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError hanpened when Jmockit mockup System.currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, jvm, jmockit

```
@Test
public void mockNativeMethod() {
    new MockUp<Runtime>() {
        @Mock
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int availableProcessors() {
            return 999;
        }
    };
    assertEquals(999, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
}
```

MockUp Runtime.availableProcessors is Ok,but when MockUp System.currentTimeMillis,something goes wrong, the error is "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError".

```
@Test
public void testSystemNative() {
    new MockUp<System>(System.class) {
        @Mock
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        long currentTimeMillis() {
            return 0L;
        }

    };
    Assert.assertEquals( 0L,System.currentTimeMillis());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a JVM issue, unfortunately. (Before version 1.43, JMockit used an ugly hack to avoid the failure.)

Comment: my jdk env is 1.8